# What causes air voids in concrete?

Tags: concrete, construction, concrete-block

Really have no idea on what causing concrete to have air voids in it. Is it causes by evaporation of water during the hydration process?

Comment: Isn't it just air entrained in the thick concrete during the pour, especially as it  moves past rebar?

Answer (score 3):

When concrete is mixed it has air trapped in the mix. When pouring walls we use vibrators to get the air out. With smaller pours hitting the forms with a hammer helps.